# Java - Checked and Unchecked Exception: Compiler level checks

Tags: java, exception

What is the difference between an **`IOException`** class that extends the **`Exception`** class and **`RuntimeException`** class that also extends **`Exception`** class?

Consider this code:

```
public class IOExceptionvsRuntime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new IOException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Although both these classes extend the **`Exception`** class and yet the **`IOException`** has to be handled whereas compiler does not enforce handling of **`RuntimeException`**. I know the conceptual difference between the two that `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception whereas `IOException` is a checked one.

It seems like there is some compiler-level handling, and I was interested in knowing more about how the compiler handles these.

Comment: This is quite a vague question - the compiler enforces certain behaviour for checked exceptions, just like it does for many other aspects of the language/type system.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: True that the compiler enforces certain behaviour for checked exceptions. But since both are extending exception class, I was curious on how the compiler distinguishing between these two. Such as type-checking (instance of RuntimeException). Was more interested in the programatic logic that compiler uses. Thanks!